# android different marker touch event to each marker

Tags: android, google-maps, ontouchlistener, marker

I'm trying to add different marker touch event for each `marker` on google map. I  have created separate object to each marker and added touch event listener to each of them. But when i `click` on each of the `marker` the output is the same for each of the marker. Need help!!!

Comment: please share your code here..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to create separate objects of every marker , you can identify marker in "OnMarkerClickListener()" listener ,use conditional statements (if ,else-if,else) and do whatever you wanna do in those conditions.
create an array of different titles of marker & use it while you are adding marker to the map by looping or whatever you prefer.

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       if (marker.getTitle().toString().equals("Current Location"))
         {
           //do code here for current location marker.
          }else if(marker.getTitle().toString().equals("Secondary Location")){
             //do code here for Secondary location marker.
           }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please approved it as your answer if this is helpful.

Comment: actually i had made mess in my code...i will surely try this solution ....this might be the correct solution..Thnx for the reply